# Как запускать/найти НУЖНУЮ JAVA из терминала на MAC OS? Более безопасным способом

Tags: linux, macos, unix, mac, path

Если я редактирую переменную PATH, добавив путь в ***/etc/paths*** (он же /private/etc/paths) и добавляю путь к java выше остальных

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

то при запросе пути до java выводится всё нормально

```
➜  ~ which java
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

Но если системный файл path оставить без изменений, а путь до java прописать в ***/etc/paths.d/наш_файл_с_путём_до_java***, то при запросе пути выводится следующее:

```
➜  ~ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

НО он есть в переменной PATH

```
➜  ~ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/sambalinski/Yandex.Disk.localized/Documents/Java/Apache/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin
```

Первый вариант работает потому, что когда я вручную редактирую системный файл paths, то вношу путь до java в **самый верх списка**, и при запросе *which java* выводится верный путь. Ибо если я вношу путь в конец системного файла path, то при запросе пути получаю тот же результат, когда я вношу путь в ***/etc/paths.d/наш_файл_с_путём_до_java***.

Как можно получить нужный результат, не трогая системный файл paths (из-за соображения безопасности)?

MAC OS 10.14.3

Comment: в `profile` (macos же импортирует его в начале сессии?) или в `bashrc` вписать не пойдёт?

Comment: Много читал про profile, но у меня его просто нет. Я решил проблему по-другому.
У меня zsh вместо bash, я добавлял в ~.zshrc некоторые строки:
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
export M2_HOME=/Users/имя_пользователя/Documents/Java/Apache/apache-maven-3.6.0

export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$M2_HOME/bin

Но по прежнему не работало до тех пор, пока я просто не поменял местами последовательность.

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$M2_HOME/bin:$PATH

Сначала мои переменные, затем переменная PATH.

Comment: то что `~/.profile` или `/etc/profile` нет не значит, что они не будут импортироваться, если их создать... и bash и zsh должны импортировать их в начале интерактивных сессий, а также они должны были бы импортироваться в начале запуска гуёвой сессии... но вот второе на mac, яхз, работает али нет... ну и про `export PATH=`, если честно, я подразумевал, что уже понимаешь...